# behat undefined step although it should be defined

Tags: php, windows, selenium-webdriver, behat, mink

I am using behat on windows7 ..it's my fourth day of struggle today...I have written a feature

```
#homepage.feature

Feature: To test the Home page loads successfully.

Scenario:
     Given I am in a session
     When I request the page "index.php"
     Then I should get some content
```

and defined steps

```
 /**
 * @Given /^I am in a session$/
 */
public function iAmInASession() {
    $driver = new \Behat\Mink\Driver\Selenium2Driver(
            'firefox', 'base_url'
    );

    global $session;
    $session = new \Behat\Mink\Session($driver);

    // start session:
    $session->start();

}

/**
 * @When /^I request the page "([^"]*)"$/
 */
public function iRequestThePage($page)
{
    global $session;

    $session->visit($page);


}

/**
 * @Then /^I should get some content$/
 */
public function iShouldGetSomeContent()
{
    global $session;
    if( $session->getPage()->getContent() )
        echo $session->getPage()->getContent();
    else
        throw new Exception("The page couln't load successfully!");
}
```

It's also showing me 147 undefined scenarios and 878 undefined steps from the default ones while some of the steps are defined in FeatureContext.php

Please Help!!!

Comment: are you sure you execute the proper scenario?

Answer (score 1):

I'm sorry , there were a couple of mistakes I was making ....I did not create the features directory , instead was adding my features to the vendor\behat\behat\features directory and the step definitions to vendor\behat\behat\features\bootstrap\FeatureContext.php

To make it work I had to create features directory in root of project by typing 
vendor\behat\behat\bin\behat --init in command prompt

All features should reside in this directory and steps should go in root\features\bootstrap\FeatureContext.php

Further the uri should be 'http://'.localhost/Project/.$page in $session->visit()

Hope this helps someone!

Comment: For future reference keep in mind that you should never touch anything in the vendors directory. This directory consists of code from other projects and as such any changes that you make will be erased if you run "Composer update" or "composer install" again. If you need to modify to fix a bug or add a feature that cannot be done as a plugin then fork the repo in GitHub and then use composer inline aliasing to have it treat your repo fork as though it is the repo that it is forking. This allows you to use your code fixes/upgrades while waiting for your code to be merged into the project.